# Extract a portion of a url

Tags: php

I am trying to extract a portion of a URL using regex.

An example of my url would be:

```
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=food
```

Using php, how could I extract the data in the q variable or the sourceid variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this. Instead, use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str).

```
$params = array();
$url= "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=food";
$url_query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($url_query, $params);
echo $params['q']; // Outputs food
```

[Demo](http://viper-7.com/x653bT)

Answer (score 1):

A [perfect tutorial for what you're trying to accomplish](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-parse-str/):

```
$parts = parse_url('http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=food');
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['q'];
```